# Is it possible to convert from JSON to domain object with @RequestParam

Tags: java, spring, rest, jakarta-ee

I am doing a multipart request from a JavaScript script (AngularJS) and I get the JSON data as the first part, and an optional file as the second. Is it possible to have the @RequestParam("data") automatically converted from JSON to a class in my application? Like `@RequestParam("data") Dog dog`

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Use @RequestBody annotation before your object (http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestbody):

```
public void jsonMethod(@RequestBody Dog dog)
```

Note: you must have jackson to convert json to your custom object. Jackson maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
   <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
   <version>1.7.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: But this is a multipart request...I can optionally get a @RequestParam("file") too

Comment: @LuckyLuke There is also `@RequestPart` you might want to look into.

Answer (score 2):

Define your method signature like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/jsonRequest")
public @ResponseBody SomeResult jsonHandler(@RequestBody(required=false) Dog dog, 
       @RequestPart(value="part2", required=false) String part2) {
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to use Jackson.
Use @RequestBody annotation for incoming parameter.
Add dependency for codehous.jackson.
And add JsonConverter to spring context file

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
  <mvc:message-converters>
     <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter"></bean>
   </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

By the way, you can take a look at the tutorial here. they use JSON and spring MVC: [sites.google.com/site/upida4j/example](https://sites.google.com/site/upida4j/example)