# AngularJS send data to spring mvc method

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-mvc

Hi everyone i'm trying to send data as param to spring mvc method that should catch param using @RequestParam :

```
@ResourceMapping(value="send")  
public void send(ResourceResponse response,@RequestParam("message") String message) throws JsonGenerationException, JsonMappingException, IOException{      
    System.out.println("send method invocked");
    System.out.println("message === >" + message);
    .........
```

and my angular JS script (not work) is as follow

```
 var message = "message="+JSON.stringify({
                "name" : $scope.message.name ,
                "email" : $scope.message.email ,
                "tel": $scope.message.tel,
                "id_subject":$scope.message.selectedSubject ,
                "content" : $scope.message.content
              });
              console.log("valid");
              $http.post('${send}', message)
              .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

              })
              .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {

              });
```

method from controller throw exception (Required String parameter 'message' is not present)
please help

Comment: You should try @RequestBody with POST httpmethod, it is better approach to handle json data

Comment: it s JSR 286 not a simple spring web mvc

Answer (score 2):

Controller.java:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/send", 
method = {RequestMethod.POST}, 
consumes = MimeTypeUtils.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
public void place(@RequestBody Message msg) {
    //do something with msg
}
```

Message.java:

```
public class Message {

    //All your fields
    private String name;
    private String email
    //and so on...

    /*
    * Getters and setters for the fields.
    * You can use @Data annotation from Lombok library 
    * to generate them automatically for you.
    */
    public String getName() { return name; }
    public String getEmail() { return email; }
}
```

Angular part:

```
var message = {name: $scope.message.name, email: $scope.message.email};
$http.post('/send', message)
  .success(function() {
    console.log("msg sent");
  })
  .error(function() {
    console.log("msg failed");
  });
```

You may also need to configure Spring to use Jackson for JSON conversion:

[Is it possible to convert from JSON to domain object with @RequestParam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18280208/is-it-possible-to-convert-from-json-to-domain-object-with-requestparam)

Comment: first thank you for repley Mr Arseny. 
your code is for spring web MVC application i use JSR 286 ( portlet api 2 ) with Spring web MVC portlet so i can't use @RequestMapping